# Php вывод информации

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста в скрипт вывести значения.
Есть код

```
<?php

$filename="date.php";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
$infotxt = file_get_contents($filename);
$config = unserialize(base64_decode($infotxt));

} else {
echo "The file configuration file is missing. Please run the setup again";
}

вывести здесь {$this->config["title"]}

?>
```

В нем мне нужно вывести информацию из date.php, пробую так {$this->config["title"]}
 - ошибка.
Вывожу после кода, так `<?php echo $config["title"] ?>` - выводит нормально. Как получить результат внутри

`<?php   ...   ?>`

Спасибо!

Comment: ну так и выводи `echo $config["title"]`. в чем проблема? ты же итак внутри `<?php`

Comment: У меня конфиг выводит данные в post запрос     $post_data = array("title" => "$title", ......

Comment: ииииииииии? причем тут post? причем тут $post_data? причем тут  "пожалуйста в скрипт вывести значения"? и вообще причем тут `$this`? ты бы описал всё более подробнее. ибо проблема твоя какая-то не проблема

Comment: Вот запрос https://i.gyazo.com/1dda4b5e46ef07943f6d4a180d647dfb.png как в него передать значения из конфига? `echo $config["title"]` не воткнуть

Comment: так и пиши ...,'title'=>$config["title"],....

Comment: хочеш в кавычках, то ...,'title'=>"$config[title]",....

Comment: @MicroRu ... ↑ ↑ ↑

Comment: А как быть с таким вариантом:           'url' => http://site.ru/$catalog?user_id=$config["user_id"],
 Как передать user_id ? https://i.gyazo.com/0b8d7750d0967332ee6eef47680e368d.png

Comment: @MicroRu https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698204/php-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment1034762_698204

Comment: так не получилось           "url" => http://site.ru/$catalog?user_id=$config["user_id"]

Comment: @MicroRu потому что ты не понял.... у тебя `http://site.ru....` чем должна являться? строкой. а ты как пытаешься сделать? как ссылку...... + как надо отображать  ключ массива, если массив **уже** находится в строке?

Comment: я запутался:( вот, что у меня https://i.gyazo.com/78442bd9db3b7c6f35d2cd3f07882ffa.png это $user_id нужно заменить на это $config[user_id]. Массивы я вообще пока не понял...

Comment: @MicroRu ну так и замени `$user_id` на `$config[user_id]`, а не на `$config["user_id"]`

Comment: А чё, include с require'ом отменили? Зачем такие камасутры?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin а причем тут include и require?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, спасибо!